# what is the right way to check out balance of erc20 token on geth console

Tags: go-ethereum

I setup a private chain and deploy an erc20 contract. I tried sending transaction of balanceOf and can get nothing but a transaction number as the return value. how can i get the balance of erc20 on geth console? My code is given below FYI

```
var contract = eth.contract(abi).at(eth.accounts[0])
contract.balanceOf.sendTransaction(eth.accounts[0],{from:eth.accounts[0],gas:60000})
```

Comment: You need to _call_ the function, rather than send a transaction. I'm not sure what programming language you're using, so it's hard to help further.

Comment: Consider sharing your existing code.

Comment: @smarx I paste my code . I also tried call balanceOf locally, the return value is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(i'm gonna assume that you are using the web3.js... since that's what your snippet looks like.)

checking the balance doesn't require you to send a transaction

just use

```
contract.balanceOf(myaddress)
```

and it should give you the balance of the token for your address (eth.accounts[0])

Comment: As an alternative, `contract.balanceOf.call(myAddress)` should work. (Using neither `sendTransaction` or `call` lets web3.js choose the right thing for you, but it's okay to be explicit.)